# Manually load a page in jQuery mobile using ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form submission that for some reason I can't submit using the normal jQuery mobile ajax submit.
I have something like that:

```
$('form[name="myForm"]').submit(function(e){
    var self = $(this)
    if ( validatefunction( self )  ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(self.attr('action'), self.serialize(), function (response) {
            // Here I would load the server response as a page
        });
    }
});
```

the point it's I don't know how to use the server response to load a new page in jQuery mobile.

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage('#pageId');`

Comment: You just want to change page, or do you want to build new page from response data or do you want to change page and also sent response data to the new page?

Comment: I would like to build a new page from the response data